# Question about LJMU LaTeX Thesis Template

Tags: bibliographies, chapters, classicthesis

I am using the [LJMU LaTeX Template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/ljmu-latex-thesis-template/kqfmpkxwwcmr) to write my PhD thesis, and I would like to write it in french. Accordingly, to change from “CHAPTER” to “CHAPITRE”, "Bibliography" to "Bibliographie"; I tried to add the package

> \usepackage[french]{babel}

to the preamble, but it doesn't affect anything it still printing "chapter".

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot see it, The above template didn't print the prefix "Chapter". However, using

```
\usepackage[french]{babel}
```

prints the correct french name for the toc:

[image]

For all other titles you have to change the documentclass, like  `Abstract`-> `Résumé` and so on.

Comment: In which place you set \usepackage[french]{babel}?

Comment: anywhere in the preamble

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've just realized that I made some changes in the class which cause the problem. I have another question. How can I make a blanck page between chapters?

Comment: Between _every_ chapter?

Comment: Yes exactly.....

Comment: `\clearpage\null\newpage` inserts an empty page, but for the book class you can get an empty page by default if a chapter ends on an odd page, because  the new one starts always on an odd page.